# Tkinter Gif issue: black becomes white and previous frame doesn't disappear

Tags: python, tkinter, animated-gif

I'm trying to code a desktop pet in python. For that I mainly used tkinter. I managed to create a window with two gifs which follow one another, but I have an issue with the display of the frames. As you can see in the picture, the black colour became white and sometimes it completely disappeared... In addition, for one of the gifs, two frames appear at the same time, the previous one staying instead of disappearing.

This is my code :

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui

impath = '.\\Assets\\'

x = 1400
cycle = 0
check = 0

probality=10
idle_num = list(range(0,7))
cry_num = list(range(7,11))
event_number = random.randrange(probality)

#transfer random no. to event
def event(cycle, check, event_number, x):
    if event_number in idle_num:
        check = 0
        print('idle')
        window.after(500, update, cycle, check, event_number, x)

    elif event_number in cry_num:
        check = 1
        window.after(500, update, cycle, check, event_number, x)

# make the gif work
def gif_work(cycle, frames, event_number):
    if cycle < len(frames) -1:
        cycle += 1
    else:
        cycle = 0
        event_number = random.randrange(probality)

    return cycle, event_number

def update(cycle, check, event_number, x):
    # idle
    if check == 0:
        frame = idle[cycle]
        cycle, event_number = gif_work(cycle, idle, event_number)

    # cry
    elif check == 1:
        frame = cry[cycle]
        cycle, event_number = gif_work(cycle, cry, event_number)
    
    window.geometry('842x842+' + str(x // 2) + '+50')
    #window.geometry('100x100+' + str(x // 2) + '+930')
    label.configure(image=frame)


    window.after(1, event, cycle, check, event_number, x)


window = tk.Tk()

# call buddy's action .gif to an array
idle = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath + 'existerGif.gif', format='gif -index %i' % (i)) for i in range(3)]  # idle gif , 4 frames
cry = [tk.PhotoImage(file=impath + 'placeGif.gif'   , format='gif -index %i' % (i)) for i in range(8)]  # sleep gif, 8 frames


window.config(highlightbackground='white')
label = tk.Label(window)
window.overrideredirect(True)
window.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','blue')

label.pack()

#loop the program

window.after(1,update,cycle,check,event_number,x)

window.mainloop()
```

Maybe it's a format problem, I did my gifs on photoshop with png images.

Anyway if someone has an idea I'll be glad to hear it ^^
Have a nice day!

Comment: We can't diagnose code that we can't see.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)